# Can a user select and upload more than one file at a time in asp.net?

Tags: asp.net, select, upload

I made a website for a friend and he uploads a lot of pictures, around 20k per month. And sadly, I made it so he has to upload 1 at a time, because when they are uploaded they are renamed, attached to a group id and watermarked. Is there a way to allow him to select all 20 in a group and have them be uploaded and processed?

I've looked into a couple of way to do it, mostly flash, and that will not work since we are renaming and added the newly created name to the db.

Adding addition upload controls is not a solution.

If we need to make a desktop application that does the uploading, that is alright as well, but we'd like to keep it all in the asp.net environment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have used [swfupload](http://www.swfupload.org/) for flash-based uploads many times. I don't see why that would stop you from renaming and/or adding the uploaded files to a database, either. Once the file is on the server, you can do anything you like.

Comment: True, but once the file is on the server, how will I know what file is what? All of the files are stored in the same folder, maybe that needs to be reworked.

Comment: The way swfupload works, you can have it upload to a separate .ashx page. The control uploads the files one at a time to that control, so you can just do whatever processing you need there.